# Call a Linux executable from C ( Ubuntu )

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, dns, executable

Normally I call the following executable like

```
./DNS www.google.com A
```

But when I want to call it from another location like

```
/home/ion/workspace/DNS/Debug/./DNS www.google.com A
```

It throws me segmentation fault

I need these because I want to call it from another C application like

```
sprintf(command,"/home/ion/workspace/DNS/Debug/./DNS %s %s","www.google.com","A")
```

I am not sure if this is correct to call an executable like that. Can anyone can help me please? Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the complete code that you're using

Comment: You will need to look into [exec](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) and its family of fun.

Comment: And what's with that "/./"  in the path name? Get rid of it.